# Appcelerator Studio Corporate Proxy

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I have been having trouble with the latest Appcelerator Studio behind a corporate proxy.

- I have tried manually entering my credentials into the studio preferences.
- I have tried using cntlm and pointing the studio to that.

I keep getting locked out of my account.

Has anyone had any luck doing this?

Comment: Did you follow http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Using_Studio_From_Behind_a_Proxy?

Comment: I did follow that guide, I also tried using cntlm and pointing Appcelerator Studio to that. I also spoke with my corporate proxy team and all the URLs listed are already whitelisted. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the studio and now I am getting the following error on my corporate and home networks: 

| ERROR  | The registry server is currently unavailable. Please try again in a few minutes or contact Appcelerator Support at support@appcelerator.com

Comment: That seems to confirm that somehow the software can't reach the servers. Please use Intercom (the ? icon on the bottom right on our websites) or send an email to support@appcelerator.com so they can assist you with this issue.

Comment: Does the proxy setting in the studio support NTLM authentication? I have also tried `appc config set proxyServer <server>` from the command line and it didn't work

Comment: I have now done fresh installs of Node v4.4.3 and CLI v5.2.2 running `appc login -l trace` returns:

`Get the registry...
Do login...
login from : cli
registry result undefined undefined true undefined true 1
detected server issue, will re-try again in 1000ms undefined`

Comment: Please contact support so they can dive into this with you. Stack Overflow is primarily meant for technical questions, not tooling.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already found a solution, I have found this to work with Appcelerator CLI:

**Activate Authenticated Proxy Usage**

```
appc config set proxyServer http://DOMAIN%5CUSERNAME:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PROXY_PORT
```

**Deactivate Proxy Usage**

```
appc config set proxyServer
```

> Replace `DOMAIN`, `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` with your authentication credentials.
>   Replace `PROXY_SERVER` with the domain name or ip address of your proxy server
>   Replace `PROXY_PORT` with the port that your proxy is listening on.

Comment: I am new to appcelerator, I wanted to run how do you run above command? where do you find 'appc' command?